# Oracle: handle different date format

Tags: oracle, date

Assume we have a VARCHAR2 column called `MyDate`
Assume it contains the following values:

13/02/2001

13-gen-2001

I have to convert this field to a DATE value. But TO_DATE fails either on some values or on the others.

```
TO_DATE(MyDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(mydate, '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}') THEN
                TO_DATE(mydate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(mydate, '\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{4}') THEN
                TO_DATE(mydate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
        END
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this

```
CASE WHEN instr(labour_contract_expiry, '-') > 0 THEN
      to_date(LABOUR_CONTRACT_EXPIRY,'DD-MON-RRRR')
ELSE
      to_date(LABOUR_CONTRACT_EXPIRY,'DD/MM/RRRR')
END,
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you can do something like

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(YOUR_COLUMN,'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' THEN TO_DATE(MyDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(YOUR_COLUMN,'\d{2}-\D{,3}-\d{4}' THEN TO_DATE(MyDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')        
     WHEN ...
```

etc.